# How to select closet element in jQuery and fire change event to file input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 2 TDs, its `HTML` is something like below: Here I want to send ajax request when as soon as file input change.

File is changing when `change-image` button click.

```
  <tbody> 
      <tr>
        <td class='center'>
          <div class='p-img'>
            <img class='img-thumbnail' src='269_thumb_1543210907.jpg' width='200' height='100'>
            <div class='loader'></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='center'>
          <div class='upload-btn-wrapper'>
            <button class='btn btn-minier btn-purple change-image ' data-image_id='1374'>Change Image</button>
            <input type='file' name='myfile' />
          </div>
        </td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='center'>
          <div class='p-img'>
            <img class='img-thumbnail' src='269_thumb_1543211961.jpg' width='200' height='100'>
            <div class='loader'></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='center'>
          <div class='upload-btn-wrapper'>
            <button class='btn btn-minier btn-purple change-image' data-image_id='1380'>Change Image</button>
            <input type='file' name='myfile' />
          </div>
        </td>    
      </tr>             
    </tbody>
```

Now I want select which button is clicked by user to send ajax request.

Can anybody tell me how detect which button is click and how fire `change` event to its file input?

This is how I tried it, but not sure how to proceed. Sorry I am new to jquery.

```
$('#property_images').on('click', '.change-image', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var changeImg =  $(this).closest('tr').children('td').find('.change-image');   
  var image_id = $(this).data("image_id")

});
```

Comment: `this` is alread `'.change-image'` so why are you looping it up again??? The input in in the TD or div so look for that....

Comment: just bind the change event in file input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **change** event to detect input file change. And get the previous button by **.prev()** function and with **attr()** function get the    "data-image_id" attribute value.

```
$('#property_images').on('change', 'input[name="myfile"]', function(e){
  debugger;
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var image_id =  $(this).prev().attr("data-image_id");
  console.log(image_id); 
  var loaderDiv =   $(this).closest("tr").find(".loader");
  console.log(loaderDiv)
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. One question can you tell me how to select `.loader` class in the same `TR` when file is change.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have a reference to the button that was clicked, but than you search the table row for the button.

The file input that is with the button inside the same TD, so you need to look at the TD, not the TR

```
$(this).closest("td").find([type='file'])
```

or just use `next()`

```
$(this).next([type='file'])
```

Comment: Thank you. then can we use `change` event like this `      $(this).closest("td").find([type='file']).change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        console.log("Image selected!");
      });`

Comment: binding an event inside of an event is typically a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sir, may I know what would be the best approach for kind of scenario?

Comment: Actually I want find change `file input` and then send `ajax` request. Here button is do nothing. Its only change file input.

Comment: file input is opening when button is clicked. Then user can select a file. After selecting a file, then I want to fire `change` event to make a ajax call.

Comment: So why are you binding click and not a change event on the file input?

Comment: Yes, I think we need 'change' not `click`. isn't it?

Comment: Then we need to find which file input to send ajax. Am I right?